# What Robot Type is depicted?

Tags: mobile-robot, robotic-arm

[image: robot diagram]

[image: list of types]

What type of robot is depicted in the below picture. I can rule out Cartesian as there is revolute joints.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be basically a SCARA robot.  It's just that the tool tip has an odd extra degree of freedom.

Is the axis of rotation of $\theta_3$ really about the tip, or is it further up at the $L_2$ joint?

Comment: unsure from diagram